# Moving a Form into a Different Solution with a Different Dataset C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is a Visual Studio Questions.

So I totally blew it. I have two solutions each with several projects in it.  Each has a DataSet.XSD associated with it.

In solution1, I have project A. In solution2, I have project B. I created a form in project A that I really needed in project B. They are in different solutions.

I tried to add the form all the ways that all the advice on SO suggested but I kept running into the same problem. The dataset on Solution A is different than the dataset in Solution B so the form is looking for files with different or missing definitions. There is some overlap.

Can anyone suggest a way to meld the two datasets together so that I have the correct references when I move the form?

I know everyone on SO loves code but this is not a code question so please don't downtick me because I have no code to show.

Comment: what is your question exactly? what is "dataset"? what is "project a", "project b", "form"?

Comment: Why the negative energy?